# All Types Of Phone Number Validation Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, phone-number

How can i validate all types of phone numbers using jquery?

Means,Some formats of phone numbers are:

```
xxxxxxxxxx mobile numbers
 +91 xxxxxxxxxx mobile numbers
 xxxxxxx Land phone numbers
 xxxx xxxxxxx Land phone numbers etc..,
```

In my form there have input field to enter phone numbers .I want to validate it with possible formats of phone numbers.This is the some formats i know.I also validate it with globally.

Comment: I assume this is for a specific country? If you're looking to have all global formats it'll be one hell of a regex.

Comment: My 2c: Validate as simply and unobtrusively as possible. No one likes a form that won't submit because of crazy validation rules. Also, google helped me with this one: http://saikiran78.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/phone-number-validation-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PhoneFormat.js](http://phoneformat.com/).
It formats any phone number input to the expected phone format and drops "illegal" characters.
From their documentation:

> This is the same type of code used by cell phones when you enter a phone number into your dialer app.

here's a usage example (with jQuery):

```
$("#phone").keydown(function(){
    $("#phone").val(formatLocal("US",$("#phone").val()));
});
```

And here's your fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUcWk/)